# asp.net json serializer adding backslash "\" to my properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have an object model that looks like this:

```
public class MyObjectModel
{
  public int1 {get;set;}
  public int2 {get;set;}

  [ScriptIgnore]
  public int3 {get;set;}
}
```

In my code, I write this:

```
MyObjectModel TheObject  = new MyObjectModel();

TheObject = LoadFromQuery(); //populates the properties using a linq-to-sql query

JavaScriptSerializer MyObjectSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

string TheObjectInJson = MyObjectSerializer.Serialize(TheObject);
```

When I look at the json string TheObjectInJson, it comes out looking like this:

```
"{\"int1\":31,\"int2\":5436}"
```

The serializer adds a backslash to each property. I tried adding and removing the [Serializable] attribute above the class definition but to no avail.

Any suggestions why this is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That should be correct. When sending JSON back to the browser, all property names must be in quotes. The backslashes you see are Visual Studio escaping the strings when viewing them (I hope, you didn't mention when you're seeing this).

If you actually send that data back out on the wire it should come across as

```
{"int1": 31, "int2":5436}
```

which is proper JSON notation.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example) for an example of JSON notation.

Comment: ok, you're right, when I put the string in a literal and look at what is on the page, I see the json data correctly formatted. I was looking in the VS debugger. Hella confusing!

Comment: Yup! You'll get used to it eventually. Next time in the debugger when you're looking at a string, press the down arrow next to the magnifying glass and choose "text visualizer" and it'll show properly.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller return the type of your object (not as a string!) as a JsonResult, ie:

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult<MyObjectModel> GetMyObject()
        { 
            var theObject = LoadFromQuery(); //populates the properties (however)
            return Json(theObject);
        }
```