# Replace method not working c#? Whats wrong here

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I need an url that is created by finding a file, can get the url of that file and I get this:

```
"C:\\dev\\vsprojects\\MvcApplication4\\MvcApplication4\\hard.txt"
```

Everything is working well, and the problem comes when I replace the `\\` by `\` but it doesn't work! Here's the code:

```
string ruta = "";

foreach (var readText in
    Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\dev\vsprojects\MvcApplication4\MvcApplication4",
    "stringCon.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    ruta = readText;
}

ruta = ruta.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
//in debugger mode says ruta parameter still having
//the \\ and i cant get the content of the txt file
TextReader ReadTXT_file = new StreamReader(ruta);
//and here says that StringConexion is null, why??
string StringConexion = ReadTXT_file.ReadLine();

ReadTXT_file.Close();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp.net json serializer adding backslash “\” to my properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327048/asp-net-json-serializer-adding-backslash-to-my-properties/7327145#7327145)

Comment: I do not understand why you are trying to replace the double backslash as it shouldn't be in your string anyway. Nor do I understand what you are trying to accomplish with your `foreach`. In debugger mode it displays the backslash as correctly escaped backslash. And `StringConexion` is `null` at given point because you assign a value to it in the next line, so what value would you expect it to have.

Comment: thanks @mgttlinger i did that and you where rigth

Comment: @user2195741 I have no idea what I suggested to do but I am glad I could help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well not exactly sure **what** you're trying to do, however, your "Replace" code is outside of the loop. You need it inside otherwise you'll only be replacing the last file's text.

```
public class e{


        string ruta = "";

                foreach(var readText in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\dev\vsprojects\MvcApplication4\MvcApplication4", "stringCon.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {

                    ruta = readText;
                    ruta = ruta.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
    //in debugger mode says ruta parameter still having the \\ and i cant get the content of the txt file
                TextReader ReadTXT_file = new StreamReader(ruta);
    //and here says that StringConexion is null, why??
                string StringConexion = ReadTXT_file.ReadLine();//

                ReadTXT_file.Close(); 

                }



}
```

**EDIT**

Just realised too this won't even compile. And you class is called "e". I'm slightly scared by all of this, but nevertheless I will suggest this format for creating classes / methods...

```
public class MyProperClassName
{
    public void MyMethodName()
    {
        // do your file text operations here
    }
}
```