# How to replace "\\" to "\" with String.Replace()

Tags: c#, string, replace

I want to replace `"\\"` with `"\"` (two to just one).
I'm using:

```
string myPath = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);    
string correctPath = myPath.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

But nothing happens, the string in correctPath continues with `"\\"`

Comment: Are you looking at it in the debugger - it shows you the escaped string ...

Comment: Do you have any more sample code? You would need to do something along the lines of: 

const string s = "Darth Vader is scary.";
 Console.WriteLine(s);

 // Note:
 // You must assign the result of Replace to a new string.
 string v = s.Replace("scary", "not scary");
 Console.WriteLine(v);

Comment: I had, some one edited. I'll put again.

Comment: The string that's visible within the debugger will always display `\ ` as `\\ `. It usually confuses newcomers, but you'll learn to really appreciate it eventually, especially when you want to know, why `\r\n` isn't displayed correctly.

Comment: If you are looking at the value through Visual Studio `\` will appear as `\\`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace method not woking c#? Whats wrong here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551593/replace-method-not-woking-c-whats-wrong-here)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're probably viewing the string whilst paused in the debugger. Print the value to a console window, it's fine.

```
string myPath = @"hello\\world";
string correctPath = myPath.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
Console.Write(correctPath);
Console.Read();
```

Comment: Beat me to it! I just wrote out this exact code, and it definitely works.

Comment: Worked, thanks. (I need to wait 10 minutes to accept this answer)

Comment: The string in your sample does not contain two backslashes. There is only one. Did you mean `@"hello\\world"`?